# I got error: Cannot read properties of null(reading 'value'). TypeError: cannot read properties of null(reading 'value'). I don't understand it

Tags: reactjs, typescript, events, typeerror

I'm trying to made Vocab test note. The below code is about the registration of the words.

```
interface AddToList {
  en: string;
  ko: string;
}

const [word, setWord] = usetState<AddToList>({
  ko: "";
  en: "";
})

<input
  type="text"
  placeholder="EN"
  onChange={(event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    console.log(event, event.currentTarget, event.currentTarget.value);
    setWord((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      en: event.currentTarget.value, // << this part might cause error!
    }));
 }}
/>
```

`console.log` returns what I entered. But, I got error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value'). TypeError: cannot read properties of null (reading 'value').

So I tried to change my code like below

```
interface AddToList {
  en: string;
  ko: string;
}

const [word, setWord] = usetState<AddToList>({
  ko: "";
  en: "";
})

<input
  type="text"
  placeholder="EN"
  onChange={(event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    console.log(event, event.currentTarget, event.currentTarget.value);
    setWord((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      en: event.currentTarget?.value || "", // << I changed like this
    }));
 }}
/>
```

However, after the first alphabet that I entered, `word`'s en value became "", which means that `event.currentTarget?.value` is null or undefined. So, I tried another way.

```
<input
  type="text"
  placeholder="EN"
  onChange={(event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const inputValue = event.currentTarget.value;
    setWord((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      en: inputValue
    }));
 }}
/>
```

It' works properly. But, I don't know why... What's the different between  `en: event.currentTarget?.value || "",` and `const inputValue = event.currentTarget.value;`

Comment: You have `usetState` instead of `useState` in a couple of places. Is it a typo only in the question or also in your project? There should be no difference between the two syntaxes. As in: if one works, the other should, too. Would you be able to create a *runnable* [mcve]? Use codesandbox.io or similar, if creating a react stack snippet seems too cumbersome.